# Looking to identify Solitaire game

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

My dad (now 93 years old) used to play a two deck solitaire game with the cards laid out in 10 columns as shown in the picture.  In brief:

1. Two Decks
2. 10 columns
3. 1st column has one card, second column has two cards . . . tenth column has ten cards.
4. Cards alternate face up, face down
5. Remaining cards are used one at time and only the most recent card that is top of the pile can be used.

I am looking to identify this variant and see if I can find an online version for him.

[image: Two Deck Solitaire]

Comment: Please add more rules, such as the goal of the game.  What do you mean by the top card can be "used"?

Comment: ryanyuyu - Not very good at the terminology, but the remaining cards that are not originally placed in the 10 columns are revealed one at a time.  If the revealed card can be used then it is placed in the play area, if not another card is dealt on top it, now that card must be placed on the board, before the card below it can be played.

Comment: How do you play the cards on top of each other? Red on red? Red on black? Clubs on clubs? 5's on 4's or maybe 4's on 5's? Do you use a foundation, and do you build from ace up?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I’ve found is Batsford.

Batsford uses 2 decks, and has 10 tableau stacks going from 1 to 10. You didn’t mention how many foundation piles; but given 2 deck I would assume 8 foundation piles.

The problem is that Batsford only has the top card facing up in the tableau stacks. Perhaps this is a Batsford variant that alternates the cards face up and face down in the tableau stacks...

Batsford is available online at https://www.classicsolitaire.com/batsford.html.

Comment: Christopher, I tried Batsford and has all of the same rules that my Dad uses.  This is a very close approximation, the only difference is the alternating pattern.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Christopher, on second look, looks like Batsford allows you to go though the Reset deck more than once.  That is not allowed in the variation I am seeking.  It makes solving it difficult.  Using shuffled two decks of cards, you end up solving it 1 out 20 times (estimated).    Also the fact that there are face-up cards that you are seeking makes the game more fun and adds some strategic elements I found missing in Batsford.

Comment: With only two rule differences it seems very likely to be a variant of Batsford. Hopefully someone else will recognize and know it’s name. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe your dad made this variant. So you can call it Dadsford.

Comment: You can use this like to play Batsford since the other link doesn't seam to work anymore: https://www.isolitairegames.com/batsford.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but my Dad taught me this game - the setup is as is shown in the picture.  You play cards on the tableau on each other ie alternating red and black descending in value.  in this example the nine of clubs can be played on either of the red tens.  The goal is like other solitaire games.  Get the piles of Ace through King in each suit - you'll have 8 piles as there are two decks.

RULES:
As you play, when a column empties out you can place a King at the top of the column (promotion) and then play descending cards in alternating colors.

An Ace starts the pile and you can place same suit cards on the Ace piles in ascending order - ie 2, 3, 4 etc - these piles are placed on the side of the tableau (or on top) like regular solitaire

You can take a card from the Ace pile and bring it back to the tableau as needed as long as it's put on a card of immediate higher value of opposite color - ie bring the six of clubs back and play it on the seven of hearts. IF you don't play with this rule, it is very hard to win at this solitaire.

GAMEPLAY:

After dealing the tableau, you will have 49 cards remaining in the deck - this is not a 'reset' deck - the cards in this deck will be played on the tableau - here's how:

After you've dealt the tableau, play as many cards on each other as you can, flipping over any face-down cards as they get revealed. In the picture above, you can play the four of hearts on the five of clubs and flip over the face-down card that is revealed when the four is moved.  The Ace and Two of clubs can be removed to start a pile of clubs (placed to the side or top  of the tableau the two on top of the Ace).

When you can't play on any other cards on the tableau or play cards on the Ace piles, you need to start placing the remaining deck cards on the tableau.  This is why it's not a reset deck.

To place the cards from the deck on the tableau:

Never put a card on the first column - it's like a free column
Never put a card on a column that is empty
Never put a card on a column that is headed by a King - that is, a column that is headed by a King that you promoted. (in the example picture you would put a card on the third column, because even though it is headed by a King, it hasn't been promoted
Do place one card at the bottom of every column (from column 2-10 and in keeping with the above rules) - this is considered one turn.

Then do the gameplay as in the beginning until you're stuck again.  Once you can't move, place another card on each column.  You will alternate between the gameplay and placing cards from the deck until you have no more cards on the deck and can't make any legal moves.

The game can get very messy and there are a lot of moving parts to consider.  It is a difficult game to win - the estimate of 1 in 20 sounds about right, but it is satisfying.

I think this version may be popular in the Middle East - hope this helps